# How to fix width and height is % in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$image_crop = $('#upload-image').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    viewport: {
        width: 300,
        height: 250,
        type: 'square'
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 350,
        height: 300
    }
});
```

I want to give width and height in percentage. in the above code width and height in px.

Comment: width:300+'%'; this is the way

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it possible for this moment

Here's a link to opened issue: https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/issues/280

Nevertheless, you can try to set values like this

```
viewport: {
  width: 80 + '%',
  height 80 + '%'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't give the `height` and `width` directly in percentages.
Checked the source and found out that the parameters aupplied are attached in this manner:

(https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/blob/188585563069754b60385e590e8767cb9b394302/croppie.js:369)

```
 css(viewport, {
        width: self.options.viewport.width + 'px',
        height: self.options.viewport.height + 'px'
    });
```

But you can convert the percentages to absolute values beforehand and then pass it

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function cropImage(widthPercentage, heightPercentage) {
            var absWidth = (widthPercentage * $('#upload-image').width()) * 100;
            var absHeight = (heightPercentage * $('#upload-image').height()) * 100;
            $image_crop = $('#upload-image').croppie({
                enableExif: true,
                viewport: {
                    width: absWidth,
                    height: absHeight,
                    type: 'square'
                },
                boundary: {
                    width: 350,
                    height: 300
                }
            });
        }
    });
```